# Python Input Function duplicating

Tags: python, input

Is there a reason why my input is being asked twice? I need to use three separate functions to calculate the formula using user input.

```
def values():
    initInv=input("Enter initial investment ")
    rate=input("Enter the interest rate in the form of a decimal ")
    freq=input("Enter the frequency that the interest is paid out per year ")
    years=input("Enter the number of years the interest is compounded for ")
    return initInv, rate, freq, years

w, x, y, z=values()

def typecast():
    invest=int(w)
    RATE=float(x)
    FREQ=int(y)
    time=int(z)
    return invest, RATE, FREQ, time

first, second, third, fourth=typecast()

def formula():
    P=first
    r=second
    n=third
    t=fourth
    A=(P*(1+(r/n))**(n*t))
    return A

values()
typecast()
formula()
```

Answer (score 0):

You call `values` twice. Once after defining it: `w, x, y, z=values()` Then again at the end: `values()`

Edit: the same with `typecast`. You call it twice too.

Here's the code with duplicates removed.

```py
def values():
    initInv=input("Enter initial investment ")
    rate=input("Enter the interest rate in the form of a decimal ")
    freq=input("Enter the frequency that the interest is paid out per year ")
    years=input("Enter the number of years the interest is compounded for ")
    return initInv, rate, freq, years

def typecast():
    invest=int(w)
    RATE=float(x)
    FREQ=int(y)
    time=int(z)
    return invest, RATE, FREQ, time

def formula():
    P=first
    r=second
    n=third
    t=fourth
    A=(P*(1+(r/n))**(n*t))
    return A

w, x, y, z=values()
first, second, third, fourth=typecast()
A = formula()
```